# Enumerating Registry Values in Go (Golang)

Tags: windows, go

I'm trying to enumerate over a list of values in the Windows registry using Go, but I'm running into some trouble.  I've tried two approaches: using both the Go-provided `syscall` library to call into `RegEnumValue`, as well as [using a Windows API wrapper by lxn](https://github.com/lxn/win).  In both cases, I'm having the same issue.  This is the code I'm using (which is currently using the win library from lxn):

```
var root win.HKEY
rootpath, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM")
fmt.Println(win.RegOpenKeyEx(win.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, rootpath, 0, win.KEY_READ, &root))

var name_length uint32 = 72
var name *uint16
var key_type uint32
var lpData *byte
var lpDataLength uint32 = 72
var zero_uint uint32 = 0
fmt.Println(win.RegEnumValue(root, zero_uint, name, &name_length, nil, &key_type, lpData, &lpDataLength))

win.RegCloseKey(root)
```

In this case, `RegEnumValue` always returns code 87, which [MSDN's only explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is "The parameter is incorrect."

Does anyone have any ideas that can point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A member of the Golang sub-reddit pointed out that I was not actually allocating any memory to the buffers passed in to `RegEnumValue`.  As such, I've corrected the above example to the following:

```
var name_length uint32 = 72
var key_type uint32
var lpDataLength uint32 = 72
var zero_uint uint32 = 0
name := make([]uint16, 72)
lpData := make([]byte, 72)

win.RegEnumValue(root, zero_uint, &name[0], &name_length, nil, &key_type, &lpData[0], &lpDataLength)
```

Obviously, the "magic number" of 72 should probably be replaced with something else.  There is another method called `RegQueryInfoKey` that can retrieve information about the registry key to allocate the correct number of bytes for the largest name and value in the key.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to decode the lpData that is returned. Any hints as to what you are doing with lpData?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe someone found this useful:

```
const regKey = `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`

func getSettingsFromRegistry() (settings map[string]string, error) {
    settings = make(map[string]string)

    k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, regKey, registry.QUERY_VALUE)
    if err != nil {
        
        return fmt.Errorf("open registry key %q: %w", regKey, err)
    }
    defer k.Close()

    params, err := k.ReadValueNames(0)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("read value names %q: %w", psaConfRegistry32, err)
    }

    for _, param := range params {
        val, err := getRegistryValueAsString(k, param)
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("get value as string %q: %w", k, err)
        }
        settings[param] = val
    }

    self.Log.Printf("%#v\n", settings)
    return
}

func getRegistryValueAsString(key registry.Key, subKey string) (string, error) {
    valString, _, err := key.GetStringValue(subKey)
    if err == nil {
        return valString, nil
    }
    valStrings, _, err := key.GetStringsValue(subKey)
    if err == nil {
        return strings.Join(valStrings, "\n"), nil
    }
    valBinary, _, err := key.GetBinaryValue(subKey)
    if err == nil {
        return string(valBinary), nil
    }
    valInteger, _, err := key.GetIntegerValue(subKey)
    if err == nil {
        return strconv.FormatUint(valInteger, 10), nil
    }

    return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to get type for sub key %q", subKey)
}
```

REG_BINARY values will looks like "\x01\x00\x00..."